# Delphi: Where is the shortcut that started the application?

Tags: delphi

I'm aware that the directory where the current executable is located can be found using Application.Exename.

But when the application was started using a shortcut in another directory?  Can I find the address of THAT directory, where the shortcut is, as I'd like to create some files there?

Using XE2.  Many thanks.

Comment: I think you'd be better off passing the information in a command line argument. Otherwise you'll force users to start your app with a shortcut and that's a needless limitation. I've never come across an app that does what you propose. I think that should be a warning sign. Have you seen such an app? Why don't you store data in one of the standard places?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thanks, that's working now, as long as I pass the directory name in full as parameter 1 to the target, like: "C:\myprogram.exe" "C:\thisdir\"  But is it not possible to give parameter 1 as something like "%CD%" ? — I've tried numerous variants but can't make it substitute the %CD% by the actual dir name.

Comment: That won't work. Hard code the directory. Why are you going against the grain in this way? What is your goal?

Comment: I should explain that I was replying to your first message, which seems to have disappeared, and I hadn't seen the other comments made in the meantime, and which I'll have to study.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Giomach: I'm a little unclear on what you are asked for. Do you want to retrieve the folder path where the shortcut itself physically resides? Or a path where the shortcut tells the app to start in? The former is not usually useful. The latter is set via the shortcut's "Start in" field, which sets the app's Current Working Directory at startup. Your app can use `Windows.GetCurrentDirectory()` or `SysUtils.GetCurrentDir()` to retrieve that value. A shortcut are not the only way an app can start. A process can be spawned by `ShellExecute/Ex()` or `CreateProcess()` with a customized CWD as well.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but I agree with @David that this is wrong to do. You should be saving your files in the proper location, which is either the user's AppData\Roaming or AppData\Local folder if it's per-user data or the Public\Documents\<Your App or Company> folder if it's global data. The user may not have write privileges where the shortcut file is located (for instance, shortcuts created by an administrator when the app is installed that the standard user can't change).

Comment: I'd hate if an application created files on the desktop, or in the start menu for that matter. Both are common places to put shortcuts.

Comment: @All: To explain the situation in which I think this is appropriate will take more than one comment. My program is a graphical interface to a command-line program (written by someone else).  Users are likely to have their different datasets for the CL program, which they may want to place in separate directories, and to run my program from such directories.  Rather than have them copy my program into each data directory, I opted to have them place my exe in the same directory as the CL exe, and have them create a shortcut to my exe from each of their data directories.

Comment: @All, part 2. The present query arises because some aspects of the situation are specified to my exe in a configuration file, and originally I didn't envisage these varying between different datasets on the same computer, only between different computers.  It now seems that such intra-computer variation might be desirable, and the plan now is: if there is a dataset-specific configuration file present, use it; otherwise use the central configuration file. The problem: where to see if there is a data-specific configuration file – in the directory with the shortcut which started my program.

Comment: @All, part 3 of 4: The user's input data will also be in that directory, so if I could afford to wait until it is nominated, I would know the directory.  But that is too late: the configuration file is needed before making any choices, as it determines the range of choices for some of the questions, and all are displayed onscreen at once. BTW, I don't see that it would be any more dangerous to fetch this directory name from the shortcut than it would be to fetch it from the input filename — it will be the same directory!

Comment: @All, part 4 of 4: So any user who wants a separate configuration file for a dataset will add a parameter to the target of the shortcut for that dataset, giving the directory containing the shortcut.  It would be simpler if this parameter could be invariable in form (eg. %CD%) rather than having to be hard-coded and therefore different for each directory (as well as being rather long), but it looks like that is how it must be, unless I can use STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME, which I will be trying out very soon, and for which I am grateful in spite of the caveats.  The end!

Comment: Following Remy's hint above, I'm having the users blank out the "Start in" property of the shortcut, which will set the app's current working directory to the directory containing the shortcut, and this can then be found by calling GetCurrentDir before it has a chance to change.  This should allay the fears which have been expressed over the misuse of STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME, but it gives the user an extra task to do. Thanks again to all who offered advice.

Answer (score 10):

You can do that using [GetStartupInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683230.aspx) with the [`STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331.aspx#STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME) flag:

```
const
  STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME = $800;

function GetShortcutName(out LinkName: string): Boolean;
var
  si: TStartupInfo;
begin
  Result := False;
  FillChar(si, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0);
  GetStartupInfo(si);
  if (si.dwFlags and STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME) <> 0 then
  begin
    Result := True;
    LinkName := si.lpTitle;
  end;
end;
```

Test code (tested on Win7 64 with XE8 and Delphi 10 Seattle - not tested on Win8 or 10):

```
program GetShortCutTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Windows;

var
  sLink: string;

begin
  if GetShortcutName(sLink) then
    WriteLn('Shortcut: ' + sLink)
  else
    WriteLn('Not run from shortcut.');

  ReadLn;
end.
```

You can test it by running the test app (which will show 'Not run from shortcut.'), and then creating a shortcut to the test app and executing that shortcut (which then shows 'Shortcut: ' and the name of the .lnk file).

Comment: I have never heard of this feature. When would this be useful, instead of the shortcut setting the app's Current Working Directory? A shortcut can be moved around, is that why one would not want to rely on the CWD? What if the app is launched in code instead of a shortcut? Or is launched via a shortcut that has an explicit "Start in" path? Knowing which path to use then gets a bit more complicated. If `STARTF_TITLEISLINKNAME` is used, I guess you could use `IShellLink` to load the shortcut and check its `GetWorkingDirectory()` method, and if not set then fallback to the shortcut's path.

Comment: @Remy: It's documented in the linked MSDN page. It allows the application to determine whether it's started from a shortcut or not by querying the startup info. I've never had a use for it myself, but MS makes it available. It was undocumented for quite a while, but David pointed out in a now deleted comment that it is now.

Comment: yes, I read the documentation. I was merely stating that I had never heard of that flag before today (who ever uses `GetStartupInfo()` manually these days?). But really, is it ever useful to use the path to the link file itself? Sure, Microsoft makes it available, but who actually needs to use it when other solutions are available? Just saying.  No need to comment further.

Comment: Good one! I'd never read further after I read 'lpTitle' - no mention of additional features...

Comment: Hmmm.... interesting... Our users in intranet tend to copy shortcuts from shared folders to desktop, and then do not exit from programs. So updating the program becomes rather hard. Of course one can do a separate launcher exe, but this might work as well....

Comment: Another idea that I did not made my research upon - there are special kinds of LNK-files that do not launch command lines, but launch some GUID object (COM?) instead, like ones of MS Office. Maybe that way gives more info...