# Delphi - How to get the full path of the .lnk-File that opened my Application?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I have an Application and I create a Shortcut to said Application on my Desktop and another one on a different drive.

When I open my Application through one of these shortcuts, I'd like to set a Label to the path of whatever shortcut opened it.

I managed to extract meta-Information of the shortcut but only when I have the full path of the .lnk-File. Unfortunately I don't determine where Shortcuts will be created therefore I need a more dynamic solution.

If anyone can help me on this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I probably picked the wrong dupe. A better one would have been http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825869/finding-the-shortcut-a-windows-program-was-invoked-from

Comment: the duplicate helped. Will this thread be deleted now?

or should I post the delphi-specific code and close the question?

Comment: also, this one is an even better duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267584/delphi-where-is-the-shortcut-that-started-the-application

since it is also written with delphi in mind, I just found it thanks to your dupe though

Comment: This really doesn't need to be Delphi specific. Calling Windows API functions is pretty much verbatim translation. But by linking to the question in the comment, all these questions are nicely linked now. There's nothing to be gained by deleting this particular post. I expect it will remain. That's fine. Please don't post any code here. In any case, you can't write an answer to a closed question, and you should not write an answer in a question edit. The dupes have all that is needed.